# Populate Arrays of Structures from a File

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a .dat file filled with ints and doubles that I need to populate an array of structures with, and I'm having issues figuring out the syntax.

Here is the file:

```
9383      8.86
2777     69.15
7793     83.35
5386      4.92
6649     14.21
2362      0.27
8690      0.59
7763     39.26
540     34.26
9172     57.36
5211     53.68
2567     64.29
5782     15.30
2862     51.23
4067     31.35
3929     98.02
4022     30.58
3069     81.67
1393     84.56
5011     80.42
6229     73.73
4421     49.19
3784     85.37
5198     43.24
8315     43.70
6413     35.26
6091     89.80
9956     18.73
6862     91.70
6996     72.81
```

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct student
{
    double score;
    int id;
    char grades;
} Student;

int getScores(FILE *input, Student class);

void main(void)
{
    char filename[] = "scores.dat";
    FILE *input;
    Student class[MAXNUM];
    int numScores;
    double average;

    input = fopen("scores.dat", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("EOF");
        exit(1);
    }
}


int getScores(FILE *input, Student class)
{
    double s;
    int i, count = 0;

    while(fscanf(input, "%d %lf", &i, &s) == 2)
    {
        class[count].score = s;
        class[count].id = i;
        count++;
    }
```

My main issue lies in the while loop where I am trying to populate the array with the int and doubles of the scores.dat file.

I get the following error when I compile:

```
lab5.c:53:8: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor 
vector
class[count].score = s;
    ^
lab5.c:54:8: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor 
vector
class[count].id
```

Thank you for any help or tips.

Comment: `class` is declared as a struct `Student`.  But when you subscript using `[count]` you are treating it as an array.  This is not legal syntax.  Try modifying `getScores` to take in an array instead.  And please rename it to something other than `class`.

Comment: You don't seem to call `getScores()` from `main()`.  That isn't going to help.

Comment: are you using a C++compiler? BTW:  your function `getScores()` is never called.

Comment: regarding: `void main(void)` and `exit(1);` are not compatable.  The function: `main()` has to valid signatures (regardless of what visual studio allows)  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Note: even if `void main( void )` were valid, then could not have any kind of return/exit statement that returns a value (and `exit()` always returns a value)

Comment: OT: regarding; `if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("EOF");`   1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  The function: `perror()` properly handles both part of the above

Comment: regarding: `int getScores(FILE *input, Student class)`  1) please don't call the parameter `class`, Suggest `students`  2) need to indicate that it is an array of struct  Student  I.E. `struct Student students[]`

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(input, "%d %lf", &i, &s) == 2)`  Should also be checking that the `struct Student` array has not been overflowed. (resulting in undefined behavior and a possible seg fault event)  Suggest: `while(count < MAXNUM && fscanf(input, "%d %lf", &i, &s) == 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change function `getScores` definition and declaration argument `class` from

```
`int getScores(FILE *input, Student class);`
```

to

```
`int getScores(FILE *input, Student *class);`
```